# Can we update datatype of roll up summary field

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a requirement where I have to remove master-detail relations between two custom objects where there is roll up summary field on parent object. For removing relationship, there should be no roll up field on parent so I have to remove that field. Is there a way, I can change the datatype of roll up summary field? or only way is to delete it.

Comment: I believe you will have to delete the rollup summary field. You may find this causes issues with trying to re-use the deleted field's name.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you remove master-detail relationship then you can't create rollup summary field on master object right.
2. first you have to remove the rollup summary field and then master-detail relation ship on child object.
3. still if you need the rollup summary field functionality on master object then you can create new field on master object and then build the rullup summary logic using Apex Trigger / Record Triggered Flow on each insert/update/delete/undelete operations.

hope this will help your query!.